# Initialize a list in cells in specific indexes (the indexes are in a list)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a list of indexes in each of which I need to initialize a list in a specific column. I tried this:

```
index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
dataframe.at[indexes, 'column_x'] = [] * len(indexes)
```

which resulted in the error message:

```
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

I tried using loc and iloc instead of at, which also resulted in errors. I couldn't find relevant solutions.
Any suggestions will be welcomed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty series with `[]` then use `combine_first` to fill right index:

```
sr = pd.Series([[]] * len(df))
df['column_x'] = df['column_x'].mask(df.index.isin(index)).combine_first(sr)
```